# How to select picklist value based on an apex:inputField

Tags: apex, visualforce, liveagent, html5, pre-chat-api

In my LiveAgent prechat form I have a picklist for Department that has a Chat Button ID assigned to each value with a fallback button.

```
<td> <span class="chatFormLabel">Department:</span></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="liveagent.prechat.buttons">  
                    <!-- Values are
                    LiveChatButton ID's with fallback to all support button -->  
                    <option value="573R0000000CbFH,57332000000CazM">Product Name 1</option>  
                    <option value="573R0000000CbFM,57332000000CazM">Product Name 2</option>
                    <option value="573R0000000CbFR,57332000000CazM">Product Name 3</option>
                    <option value="573R0000000CbFW,57332000000CazM">Product Name 4</option> 
                    <option value="573R0000000CbFb,57332000000CazM">Product Name 5</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
```

Later in the form I have another field that is mapped to a custom field in Salesforce for Product Name on the Case object.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!case.Product_Name__c}" id="caseProductName"/>
```

My thought is to hide the Department pick list field and dynamically select one based on the Product name selected in caseProductName. Or associate a caseProductName value to be passed based on what button is selected. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my prechat form for anyone that is interested.

**The issue**
This form works 100% as expected. But a customer starting a chat would basically have to select the product they are chatting about twice. Can I select a button based on caseProductName selected, or attach a button ID to caseProductName selected? I only want one of these field to be visible in the form but still need the functionality explained here.

```
<apex:page cache="false" showHeader="false" standardController="Case" docType="html-5.0">    

    <apex:pageMessages escape="false" />



    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() { 
        function handlePageLoad() {

            var endpointMatcher = new RegExp("[\\?\\&]endpoint=([^&#]*)");
            document.getElementById('{!$Component.prechatForm}').setAttribute('action',
                                                                              decodeURIComponent(endpointMatcher.exec(document.location.search)[1]));
        } if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener('load', handlePageLoad, false);
        } else { window.attachEvent('onload', handlePageLoad, false);
               }})(); 
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() { 
        function handlePageLoad() {
            var endpointMatcher = new RegExp("[\\?\\&]endpoint=([^&#]*)");
            document.getElementById('{!$Component.prechatForm}').setAttribute('action',
                                                                              decodeURIComponent(endpointMatcher.exec(document.location.search)[1]));
        } 
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener('load', handlePageLoad, false);
        } else { 
            window.attachEvent('onload', handlePageLoad, false);
        }
    })(); 

    </script>

    <apex:form id="prechatForm">
        <script> 
        // "required" is an attribute on the vf input field tag, and cannot be overridden in the tag. so, use JS to set it after the page loads...
        var previousOnload = window.onload; 
        window.onload = function() { if (previousOnload) { previousOnload(); } document.getElementById('{!$Component.caseProductName}').required="required"; } 
        </script>

        <!-- Detail inputs -->

        <table cellspacing='5'>
            <tr>
                <td> <span class="chatFormLabel">Department:</span></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="liveagent.prechat.buttons">  
                    <!-- Values are
                    LiveChatButton ID's with fallback to all support button -->  
                    <option value="573R0000000CbFH,57332000000CazM">Product Name 1</option>  
                    <option value="573R0000000CbFM,57332000000CazM">Product Name 2</option>
                    <option value="573R0000000CbFR,57332000000CazM">Product Name 3</option>
                    <option value="573R0000000CbFW,57332000000CazM">Product Name 4</option> 
                    <option value="573R0000000CbFb,57332000000CazM">Product Name 5</option>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="chatFormLabel">First Name:</span></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="liveagent.prechat:contactFirstName" required="required" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="chatFormLabel">Last Name:</span></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="liveagent.prechat:contactLastName" required="required" placeholder="Last Name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="chatFormLabel">Subject:</span></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="liveagent.prechat:caseSubject" required="required" placeholder="Subject"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="chatFormLabel">Email:</span></td>
                <td><input type="email" name="liveagent.prechat:contactEmail" required="required" title="ex: john@doe.com" placeholder="Enter a valid email address" id="emailAddr"  pattern="^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(.\w{2,3})+$"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="chatFormLabel">Account:</span></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="liveagent.prechat:accountName" required="required" placeholder="Account Name" id="accountName"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="chatFormLabel">Product:</span></td>
                <td>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!case.Product_Name__c}" id="caseProductName"/>
                </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="right">
                    <br/>&nbsp;
                    <input type="submit" value="Request Chat" id="prechat_submit" onclick="prepForSubmit( '{!$Component.caseProductName}', '{!$Component.prechatForm}' );"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>



        <!-- Display something in the details section at the top (ex: subject text) -->
        <!--<input type= "hidden" name= "liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.displayToAgent: contactFirstName" value= "true" />-->

        <!--<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:caseSubject" value="Chat Session" id="caseSubjectText"/><br />-->

        <!-- Map the detail inputs to the Contact fields --> 
        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Contact" value="FirstName,contactFirstName;LastName,contactLastName;Email,contactEmail;" />

        <!-- Try to find the Contact by email (exact match) -->
        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Contact" value="Email,true;" />
        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Contact" value="Email,true;" />

        <!-- If the Contact is not found, then create one with the following fields set -->
        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Contact" value="FirstName,true;LastName,true;Email,true;" />

        <!-- Save the Contact on the Live Chat Transcript's Contact Loookup -->
        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Contact" value="Contact" />

        <!-- Show the Contact when it is found or created -->
        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Contact" value="true" />

        <!-- Map Case drop downs -->
        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:productName" value="" id="caseProductNameHidden"/>

        <!-- Create a Case every time -->
        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:caseOrigin" value="Chat" />
        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Case" value="Origin,caseOrigin;Subject,caseSubject;Product_Name__c,productName;Account_Name_from_Chat__c,accountName" />
        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Case" value="Origin,true;Subject,true;Product_Name__c,true;Account_Name_from_Chat__c,true" />
        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Case" value="Case" />
        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Case" value="true" />

        <!-- Link the Contact to the Case -->
        <input type= "hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.linkToEntity:Contact" value="Case,ContactId" />


        <script type="text/javascript">

        function prepForSubmit(  productNameFld, formName )
        {
            console.log('---> start prepForSubmit');
            var productName = document.getElementById(productNameFld);
            var productNameHidden = document.getElementById('caseProductNameHidden'); // grab this so we can populate and pass it into SFDC
            productNameHidden.value = productName.value;

        }


    </script>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: you are commenting the <!--<apex:inputField value="{!case.Product_Name__c}" id="caseProductName"/>--> code